# Mamp Error in OS X Mavericks

Tags: mamp, osx-mavericks, mamp-pro

I'm using Mamp Pro in OS X Mavericks when I start it I get error saying The built in apache is active which can cause a port conflict with at least one of your virtual host.

What should I do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open terminal, and use those command:

`$ sudo apachectl stop`

`$ sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`

Restart your Mac if needed.

Comment: The second command results in: `launchctl: Error unloading: org.apache.httpd`  Which after a quick search I realize just means that it is already stopped. However, it still doesn't fix things for me. I can get Apache started on port 9998, but now MySQL won't start.

Comment: MySQL issue was resolved by following this and then a restart: http://twob.net/journal/fix-for-mamp-mysql/#comment-25239 .. I also followed these steps for bonus measures: http://aralbalkan.com/1931/

Comment: I tried everything but I still get "The built-in Apache is active" in Mamp. :(

Comment: restarting if needed brought this all together for me!